# Substitutions for greek yogurt?

Tags: substitutions, yogurt

Are there any available substitutes for greek yogurt?

I don't have any in the fridge. Looking for a substitution besides regular yogurt or any yogurt based substitution. Looking to make a creamy like cold sauce for fish tacos.

Comment: Related (actually pretty much a duplicate): http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2902/what-is-the-difference-between-greek-yogurt-and-plain-yogurt

Comment: @ghoppe saw that thread. That's germane to the difference between regular yogurt and greek yogurt. While I agree regular yogurt would be a substitution; it doesn't directly answer the question.

Comment: It depends completely on what you want to do with it. If you are baking it in a batter, no non-yogurt substitution will function. If you are making a salad dressing, you could use mayonnaise and still get a good salad. In between, there are various degrees of sensitivity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sour cream could work.  It has a similar flavor to plain greek yogurt, although the consistency is somewhat different.  In fact, My fiance and I have switched to using greek yogurt in place of sour cream because of this since sour cream is higher in calories.  I think it would be just fine for a sauce.

Comment: I was thinking this, exactly. I have often seen greek yogurt used as a substitution for sour cream, so it would make sense if it worked the other way as well. Especially in the OP's original usage for a cold sauce for fish tacos.

Comment: Thumbs UP - was making hummus that called for Greek yogurt and didn't have any - used sour cream and it's delicious. Have made this with Greek yogurt in the past and I have to say - I think it's BETTER with sour cream.

Answer (score 4):

For cooking, or putting a dallop on top of a bowl of soup? Try [crème fraiche](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cr%C3%A8me_fraiche).

Answer (score 2):

Greek expat here; while roaming in various countries, I often stumble across yogurt variants that tend to be too liquid for my taste ;)

Here is what to do in that case: take said yogurt and pass it through fine cloth (typically this is a clean/unused kitchen towel). Discard the liquid and keep the now much thicker yogurt for your needs. Hint: this works brilliantly for preparing tzatziki!

Advice: 
never fail to buy some greek yogurt when you find it available, as a minimum to use it as reference in thickness/taste for whatever else you want to compare with! Also, remember, higher price may just imply quality.

Comment: While this is certainly good information, I don't see how it answers the question. The OP specifically says they are looking for something besides yogurt.

Comment: well, the method described allows you to take several liquid yogurt(-like products) and convert them to thick variants, much closer in texture to Greek yogurt.

The case is oftentimes, that stores around you have those liquid ones - fi. this was happening to me all the time while living in Amsterdam.

Comment: I get that and, again, it's good information. But the OP specifically states that they want a substitute other than regular yogurt or something yogurt-based.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mashed baking bananas (plantains) to substitute for greek yogurt.